# need help in forming sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

i have one master table and  2 tables, one is inward table and the other one is issue_return_broken table.
all the 3 tables are related using the ITEM_CODE (primary key)..
if i run the below 3 queries ,

### Master query :

```
 select item_code, item_name , item_spec, item_quantity,item_unitprice,item_value from      
 ven_inv_partmaster
 where item_code ='NAVTES13'
```

### Query 1:

```
select entry_date, quantity_in from ven_inv_inwardmaster    
 where item_code ='NAVTES13'
 group by entry_date,quantity_in
```

### query 2:

```
 select issue_date, issue_qnty,rtn_qnty,brkn_qnty from ven_inv_ibrmaster_log ibrlog  
   where ibrlog.item_code ='NAVTES13' and issue_dateid !=0
   group by issue_date,issue_qnty,rtn_qnty,brkn_qnty
```

### Query 3:

```
  select rtn_date, rtn_qnty,brkn_qnty from ven_inv_ibrmaster_log ibrlog   
   where ibrlog.item_code ='NAVTES13' and issue_dateid =0
   group by rtn_date,rtn_qnty,brkn_qnty
```

i am getting the output as below,

```
  item_code item_name   item_spec  item_quantity    item_unitprice  item_value
  NAVTES13    NAVIN         TEST13       175               15.00    2175.00
```

output1:

```
   entry_date               quantity_in
   2012-04-01 00:00:00.000      50
   2012-04-05 00:00:00.000        50
```

output 2:

```
   issue_date             issue_qnty    rtn_qnty    brkn_qnty
   2012-04-02 00:00:00.000    25             0           0
   2012-04-10 00:00:00.000    10             0           0
```

output 3:

```
   rtn_date             rtn_qnty    brkn_qnty
  2012-04-05 00:00:00.000     10            0   
  2012-04-10 00:00:00.000     9         6
```

i need to combine all these queries into a single query and need a result set like this..

```
 Date        Quantity_Inward   Quantity_Issued   Return_Quantity   Broken_Quantity
  1/4/2012          50                  0                0               0
  2/4/2012           0                 25                0               0
  5/4/2012           0                  0               10               0 
  5/4/2012          50                  0                0               0
  10/4/2012          0                  0                9               6
  10/4/2012          0                 10                0               0
```

please help me out to solve this query..

inward & ibr master table :

[image]

Comment: Why do you have/need two rows for `5/4/2012` and two rows for `10/4/2012`

Comment: In this all where do you need the master query.
     I think that is not being used.

Comment: And why are you using `GROUP BY` is queries 1-3?  Do you actually get multiple records back other-wise?  Is it possible to show us the *full* schema for the source tables, and the data returned with the `GROUP BY`

Comment: yeah man can u please show us **ven_inv_inwardmaster** and **ven_inv_ibrmaster_log** schemas to help you further     
without that I am not able to draw the query.

Comment: @Abhinav: we are not using the master query..on 5/4/2012 one entry will be in the inward table and the other entry will be in the ven_inv_ibrmaster_log  table.. i need to show all the transactions made for that particular item_code

Comment: @Dems: actually , in my previous queries i used group by clause.. i copied the same query and just modified the table names..and i forgot to remove the GROUP BY..

Comment: can you put the structure of database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine the results of your queries in the manner shown, use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html) with ordering in an outer query:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(logdate, '%e/%c/%Y') AS `Date`,
  quantity_in AS Quantity_Inward,
  issue_qnty  AS Quantity_Issued,
  rtn_qnty    AS Return_Quantity,
  brkn_qnty   AS Broken_Quantity
FROM (
  select date(entry_date) as logdate, quantity_in,
    0 as issue_qnty, 0 as rtn_qnty, 0 as brkn_qnty
  from ven_inv_inwardmaster
  where item_code ='NAVTES13'
UNION ALL
  select date(issue_date), 0, issue_qnty, rtn_qnty, brkn_qnty
  from ven_inv_ibrmaster_log
  where item_code ='NAVTES13' and issue_dateid != 0
UNION ALL
  select date(rtn_date), 0, 0, rtn_qnty, brkn_qnty
  from ven_inv_ibrmaster_log
  where item_code ='NAVTES13' and issue_dateid  = 0
) AS t
ORDER BY logdate ASC
```

You could even aggregate in the outer query if so desired (your sample output doesn't do so):

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(logdate, '%e/%c/%Y') AS `Date`,
  SUM(quantity_in) AS Quantity_Inward,
  SUM(issue_qnty)  AS Quantity_Issued,
  SUM(rtn_qnty)    AS Return_Quantity,
  SUM(brkn_qnty)   AS Broken_Quantity
FROM (
  ...
) AS t
GROUP BY logdate
ORDER BY logdate ASC
```

You might improve performance slightly by combining your queries 2 and 3 as follows:

```
  select
    date(if(issue_dateid = 0, rtn_date, issue_date)),
    if(issue_dateid = 0, 0, issue_qnty),
    rtn_qnty,
    brkn_qnty
  from ven_inv_ibrmaster_log
  where item_code = 'NAVTES13'
```

Note I have removed the `GROUP BY` clauses from your queries as your comment above suggests they are not required.